# Solving $f(f(f(x)))=x$ where $f(x)=4x(1-x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Find the number of solutions of $f^{(3)}(x)=x$ where $f:[0,1]\to[0,1], \ f(x)=4x(1-x)$

I tried substituting $x=\sin^2(\theta)$ but it didn't help.

There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3655004/734160) on the same question but I don't seem to grasp it.

Comment: I solved the problem for each n in this question ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655004/repeated-roots-f1992x-x-for-fx-4x1-x), starting from what @jjagmath did

Comment: @PatrickDanzi very nice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution $x = \sin^2 \theta$ with $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ does work:

$f(x) = 4x(1-x) = 4 \sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta) = (2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^2 = \sin^2(2\theta)$

That means that $f^{(3)}(x) = \sin^2(8\theta)$.

So you want to solve $\sin^2(8\theta) = \sin^2\theta$. Then

$$0=\sin^2(8\theta) - \sin^2\theta = (\sin(8\theta)+\sin\theta)(\sin(8\theta)-\sin\theta) $$
$$= 2 \sin(\tfrac{8\theta + \theta}{2})\cos(\tfrac{8\theta - \theta}{2})\cdot 2 \sin(\tfrac{8\theta - \theta}{2})\cos(\tfrac{8\theta + \theta}{2})=4\sin(\tfrac{9}{2}\theta)\cos(\tfrac{7}{2}\theta)\sin(\tfrac{7}{2}\theta)\cos(\tfrac{9}{2}\theta)$$

But

$\sin(\tfrac{9}{2}\theta)=0$ for $\theta = 0,\tfrac{2}{9}\pi,\tfrac{4}{9}\pi$

$\cos(\tfrac{7}{2}\theta)=0$ for $\theta = \tfrac{1}{7}\pi,\tfrac{3}{7}\pi$

$\sin(\tfrac{7}{2}\theta)=0$ for $\theta = 0,\tfrac{2}{7}\pi$

$\cos(\tfrac{9}{2}\theta)=0$ for $\theta = \tfrac{1}{9}\pi,\tfrac{1}{3}\pi$

So the answer are $x = \sin^2(\theta)$ for $\theta \in\{ 0,\tfrac{1}{9}\pi,\tfrac{2}{9}\pi,\tfrac{1}{3}\pi,\tfrac{4}{9}\pi,\tfrac{1}{7}\pi,\tfrac{2}{7}\pi,\tfrac{3}{7}\pi\}$

Comment: Ah! Very nice catch!! Can this be generalized for $f^{(n)}(x)$?

Comment: In believe so. In general $f^{(n)}(x) = \sin^2(2^n \theta)$, so it shouldn't be very different.

Comment: Yep it boils down to finding the solutions of $\sin^2(x)=\sin^2(2^nx)$(very interesting)

Comment: @jjagmath I solved the problem for each $n$ in this question ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655004/repeated-roots-f1992x-x-for-fx-4x1-x/4351704#4351704 ), starting from what you did

Comment: @jjagmath Why $\theta \in  \bigg[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\bigg ]$ why not $\bigg [-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\bigg ]$?

Comment: @mathophile Because $x$ is in $[0,1]$, not in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @jjagmath Even if $\theta \in \bigg[\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\bigg ]$ $x \in [0,1]$. Because it is $\sin^{2} \theta$

Comment: @mathophile Sorry, you're right. That's not the reason. It's because when making a substitution one wants a bijection.